# How to define a variable in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I trying to pass a variable in cakephp to a view and getting error Undefined variable: view [APP\View\ItQueries\add.ctp, line 9] and line 9 is this

```
<?php echo $this->Form->hidden('status_type', array('value'=>$view)); ?>
```

Here is how im defining my variable in the controller

```
class ItQueriesController extends AppController {

var $view = 'Open';

public function index() {
$this->ItQuery->recursive = 0;
$this->set('view', $this->view);

}

//Other Code

}
```

and here is where im trying to pass the variable as a hidden field

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('ItQuery'); ?>
<?php echo __('Add It Query'); ?></legend>
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('status_type', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value'=>$view));
?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

Can some please show me how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the variable as part of the viewVars.

To do this add this to your controller action:

```
$this->set('view', $this->view);
```

E.g.

```
class ItQueriesController extends AppController {

    var $view = 'Open';

    function index() {
        $this->set('view', $this->view);
    }

}
```

You can then access it in the view directly using `$view`

Your hidden field would look like:

```
echo $this->Form->input('status_type', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value'=>$view));
```

Comment: Its still giving me the same error. what i am trying to do is to insert the value Open into the status_type field. Do you have any idea on how i can do that?

Comment: not sure what i am doing wrong, i am still getting the same error. I have edited my question maybe you can see what i am doing wrong

Comment: What URL are you loading in the browser

Comment: localhost/intraweb/it_queries/add

Comment: This means you are hitting the add function in your controller, NOT the index function. Add the line `$this->set('view', $this->view);` to the add function instead.

Comment: if i do that its now inserting the value add instead of Open. Do i still need to make more changes?

Comment: Oh I think $this->view is already defined by the framework. Use a different name for your variable.

Comment: Thank you, now it works. What i did was in my controller i put this line.

public $variableValue = 'Open';

Then in my add function

    $this->set('variableValue', $this->variableValue);

And lastly in my add view

    echo $this->Form->input('status_type', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value'=>$variableValue));

Hope this will help out someone with the same challenge